# Load dynamic data with multiple outlet in ember.js

Tags: ember.js

I'm just getting started with Ember.js and I just can't figure out how to load dynamic data in multiple outlet. Basically, I want to do this: http://cl.ly/image/0H0e1a2j1x0I .

In the first section: click on the menu and update right content.
In the second section: click on the menu "circle" and update the content bellow.

I don't know the right solution, I started to do nested route but It doesn't seems to be the right way.

If anyone would have a tips It would be great!

Thanks

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 0):

There are at least three approaches you could take.

**1**.Since you mention multiple outlet, then you can use nested routes. You can specify rendering multiple outlets at once by using the render method within the renderTemplate function of each route. Check out a thread with fiddle that shows this approach [Ember template chaining](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19247615/ember-template-chaining/19251502#19251502) 
Separate outlets means separately bound models and controllers, but easily render state based on url. For example if you select Press releases / Articles and info is shown on the right, the url will be something like yourapp/#/all-info/press and that can be bookmarked and easily rerendered.

For example in your case it could be applied as having an outlet for showing the page and menu (*yourapp/#/all-info*),  nested outlets for showing the right part (*yourapp/#/all-info/company, yourapp/#/all-info/press, yourapp/#/all-info/media etc* ), a nested outlet for the circular menu *(yourapp/#/all-info/features*), nested outlets for each detail of circular i.e. (*yourapp/#/all-info/features/journalists, ..../features/in-place, ..../features/responsive etc*). Then you play around with the routes and render methods in order to combine as you wish.

**2**.Multiple views for each segment within a template of the page. http://emberjs.com/guides/views/inserting-views-in-templates/ . This means that you will share the model of the specified route among your views. This can either work for the whole page (single outlet) or at least for some groups of segments and combine it with few outlets from first approach.

For example in your case one outlet for whole page or one outlet for top part (side menu and details), one outlet for bottom part(ciruclar menu and details). Then each view could have separate views for menu and view for details you would end up with 2 container views top and bottom and 4 views master-detail for menus and details.

**3**.Use only one template that will render your model to the different segments. Maybe the worst approach but fine for a fast prototype before breaking it down to one of the previously mentioned solutions.